# how to modify the last set of attributes in a rails nested field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Ok, so in the rails app I'm making I have a model which needs to be adjusted before getting saved in the controller. The problem is that I don't want every nested attribute i may be modifying to have those changes, only the last (the newly created is that).

I've tried using form tags instead of relying on the form object (changing the attribute index to something like new, thinking that I would be able to access it easily) but that doesn't pass through strong params and thus doesn't get saved when I do `my_model.update(permitted_params)`. This is because I want to be able to update existing records but optionally create a new one (just one) with some attributes that need to be tweaked (in the controller that is).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my understanding of your problem is correct but I am answering in the hope that it is and it helps you but please be more specific and do share relevant code for better answers.

Solution from what I understood:

You can access the params in controller and set condition on them like:

```
  def create               # or update
    if params[:your_model][:the_attribute] == your_condition
      # You can manually edit params here before saving.
      param[:your_model][:the_attribute] = your_change
    end
    @your_model = permitted_params
    @your_model.save
  end
```

If you want to pass something that will affect your condition, you will have to permit it in permitted_params action. There is no other way as far as I know.